# Laravel passport skip redirect_uri validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I try to skip redirect_uri validation when try to take token from laravel passport.
Can you help me with that ?
It's just an configuration or is need to make an endpoint custom ?

Comment: Do you understand about grant in oauth?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for here. A redirect url of some kind is an essential part of OAuth2 when authenticating users. I don't think there's a way to not have one.

Comment: Oki, i think i understand how is work oauth2 but what I need is:
When i send an redirect_uri in request from the client app, the server ( with passport ) trust the redirect uri (was is send ) is corect and didn't make validation with request uri from oauth client what i created. 
( I'm very sorry for my bad english, pls don't be angry for that )